# Django4.1: Login fails on `localhost`, but succeeds on `127.0.0.1`

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, localhost

Before, i was using `SQLite` as a database backend, eveything was fine, but i have reached a point where an `RDBMS (postgres)` was required to setup up proper validations, queries, ...

Right after dockerizing `postgres`, i started seeing this problem.

Setup:

- Django [Not Dockerized] (with `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`)

  ```
  DATABASES = {
      "default": {
          "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
          "NAME": "localhost_db",
          "USER": "root",
          "PASSWORD": "root",
          "HOST": "localhost",  # set in docker-compose.yml
          "PORT": 5432,  # default postgres port
      }
  }
  ```
- Postgres [Dockerized]
- Redis [Dockerized]

  ```
  CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
      "default": {
          "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
          "CONFIG": {
              "hosts": [("localhost", 6378)],
          },
      },
  }
  ```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
    redis:
        restart: always
        image: redis:alpine
        expose:
            - 6378
        ports:
            - '6378:6378'
        volumes:
            - 'redisdata:/data'
        command: [ "redis-server", "--bind", "redis", "--port", "6378" ]
    db:
        container_name: pg_container
        image: postgres:alpine
        restart: always
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: root
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
            POSTGRES_DB: localhost_db
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"

    pgadmin:
        container_name: pgadmin4_container
        image: dpage/pgadmin4
        restart: always
        environment:
            PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: root@localhost.com
            PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
        ports:
            - "5050:80"
        volumes:
            - postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

volumes:
    redisdata:
    postgresdata:
```

This is my first time seeing this, anyone has ever faced this issue before ?

Comment: What do you mean by "login fails"? Do you get an error? Is it that you login on `127.0.0.1` and then open a page on `localhost` and aren't logged in anymore (This is expected behavior)? Have you by any chance set the `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` setting?

Comment: i can't login into `localhost` using my superuser credentials, but i can on `127.0.0.1`, i have not touched `session settings`

Comment: Please don't put things like the environment information in the question title, you can put it in the question _body_ (Also it would be good to repeat the question in the body,  the title is simply a summary). Your problem is still not clear what do you mean by "i can't login into localhost" please be very specific what the problem is. See [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved by clearing site data for both `127.0.0.1` and `localhost`.